# UIScrollView With Pictures Generated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have set up a UIScrollView and loaded in pictures and set it equal to the view with some offset between the pictures.  Can someone possibly explain what I might have done wrong? It shows the first picture just fine but wont let me scroll left and right to see the next ones. Do I need a gesture recognizer with the new XCode to make this work?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        int PageCount = 3;

        UIScrollView *Scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        Scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        Scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
        Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(PageCount = Scroller.bounds.size.width, Scroller.bounds.size.height);

        CGRect ViewSize = Scroller.bounds;

        UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ViewSize];
        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
        [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];

        ViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);

        UIImageView *ImgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ViewSize];
        [ImgView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
        [Scroller addSubview:ImgView2];

        ViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);

        UIImageView *ImgView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ViewSize];
        [ImgView3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];
        [Scroller addSubview:ImgView3];

        [self.view addSubview:Scroller];

    }

    @end
```

Comment: Where you have `PageCount = Scroller.bounds.size.width`, you probably intended `PageCount * Scroller.bounds.size.width`

Comment: Whoops! Sorry thank you for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually set the `contentSize` of your ScrollView to the maximum rectangle which fits all the `ImageViews` you added. For example : Lets say you want to scroll right and left and you have 4 views with each view having width 100 and you have offset of 10 in x direction. Then after adding all the 4 views to your `scrollView`, you will have to make the contentSize as below :

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( 10 + (100 + 10)*4 , scrollView.contentSize.y );
```

This will make the `scrollView` scrollable and you will see all the views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int PageCount = 3;
NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png", nil];
UIScrollView *Scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
Scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
Scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
Scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:Scroller];
int width=Scroller.frame.size.width;
int xPos=0;
for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
{
    UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, Scroller.frame.size.width, Scroller.frame.size.height)];
    [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
    Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    width +=Scroller.frame.size.width;
    xPos  +=Scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with this? it isint quite working for me and i get a crash.  I did it exactly as you typed it

Comment: never mind thank you i figured it out! :) Much smaller in the number of lines!